# How to properly support a raised bar countertop on an outdoor kitchen

Tags: kitchens, outdoor, installation, brackets

We have built an outdoor L-shaped kitchen with one side having a raised bar for eating/sitting.  The kitchen was constructed of concrete block and faced with stacked stone with a pergola.  What type of brace needs to be used to support an 18 inch wide raised bar?  Our granite installer recommended we use a flat long brace that is drilled in to the stone.  The guy who build the kitchen (and has been doing so for many,many years) isn't familiar with this type of bracket.  My guess is I am explaining it incorrectly.  Does anyone know how to interpret what we are needing?  The granite installer won't install it, he states it should be done by the kitchen installer.  In fact, all the granite estimators we have talked to and received quotes from said the same thing.  Help?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about a few pictures so we can see the problem.